# linear algebra - Prove a relation is equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know how to solve this problem :

$E$ is set of all mappings from $R$ to $R$ and $S$ is a relation defined as :

$fSg \iff \exists \psi \in E : 
\begin{cases}
    \psi \mathrm{\;is\; bijective} \\ 
    \psi \circ f = g\circ \psi
  \end{cases}$

Prove that $S$ is a equivalence relation on $E$.

Could you help me to prove this?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is go to the definition of an equivalence relation. You need to show that:  1) for all $f$, $f S f$ 2) $f S g$ implies $g S f$. and 3)  $f S g$ and  $g S h$ implies  $f S h$. For 2) and 3) use the bijections that exist from the assumptions to construct the bijections you need for the conclusions. For 1) there is a well known bijection that you can use.

Comment: Thank you but could you be more specific about 2) and 3) :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you a more detailed hint for 2) *Symmetry*:
Assume $f S g$. That means
assume $ \exists \psi \in E : 
\begin{cases}
    \psi \mathrm{\;is\; bijective} \\ 
    \psi \circ f = g\circ \psi
  \end{cases}$

You want to prove $g S f$, i.e.,that  $ \exists \phi \in E : 
\begin{cases}
    \phi \mathrm{\;is\; bijective} \\ 
    \phi \circ g = f\circ \phi
  \end{cases}$

My suggestion is that you use $\psi$ to construct $\phi$.